# Javafx : Platform runlater issue from swing to javafx

Tags: javafx

I am stuck in some situation I have application which developed in swing and some part developed in javafx.

When I use `Platform.runlater` for javafx it changes my flow of execution I want to run my Javafx block at same time .

I added some `Hbox` to `Vbox`.

Is there any way I run javafx application same time (not using `runLater`).

If I am not using `runLater` an `Exception` is thrown (Like JavafxThread pool-2...)

Comment: This question is really unclear and also it seems to suffer from the XY problem. Please describe what you're trying to do and why you don't want to use `Platform.runLater` more thoroughly.

Comment: fabian:-) I solve my problem with other way. but problem is that using runlater Javafx Thread Run After executing swig thread so i want to run it inside or same time (when it occur swing get paused javafx thread execute. hope u clear

Comment: You shouldn't post such information in the comments. If something is unclear to one user, it's likely unclear to other users. [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35079607/edit).

Comment: The bottom line is that Swing and JavaFX run on different threads of execution, so you **must** wrap code that modifies swing components in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` and code that modifies JavaFX components in `Platform.runLater(...)` (if you are not already on the correct thread). If you want to control the order of events between the two threads, then you will need to use appropriate multithreading techniques to do that. You need to [edit] your question to be much more specific about what you are trying to do (and to some extent, why you need to do it that way).

Comment: (Just a caveat: there is a system property that can be set: `javafx.embed.singleThread=true` that unifies the AWT event dispatch thread and the JavaFX Application Thread. However this was described as "experimental" way back before 1.8.0_40 and I haven't heard of any change in that status, so I would not recommend it for production.)